# Sass Arithmetic

Tags: sass

I'm trying to loop from 1 to 12 and output some span widths for an altered grid for a particular view in an app.

```
$span-width: 8.21875%;
$gap: 0.125%;
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
  $span-width: ($i * $span-width) + ($i * $gap) ;
  .span#{$i}{
    width: $span-width;     
 }
}
```

This is outputting

```
.span6 {
  width: 6162%;
}
```

How do I write the sass to calculate the widths using the usual arithmetic rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression you want is this:  `($i * ($span-width / 1%)) + ($i * ($gap / 1%))`.  Alternately, you could drop the % from your `$span-width`/`$gap` variables.

Edit:  not sure why assigning the variable to the expression isn't working (I had only tested it using @debug)

```
$span-width: 8.21875%;
$gap: 0.125%;
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    @debug (($i * ($span-width / 1%)) + ($i * ($gap / 1%))) * 1%;
    .span#{$i}{
        width: (($i * ($span-width / 1%)) + ($i * ($gap / 1%))) * 1%;
    }
}
```

Generates this:

```
.span1{width:8.34375%}
.span2{width:16.6875%}
.span3{width:25.03125%}
.span4{width:33.375%}
.span5{width:41.71875%}
.span6{width:50.0625%}
.span7{width:58.40625%}
.span8{width:66.75%}
.span9{width:75.09375%}
.span10{width:83.4375%}
.span11{width:91.78125%}
.span12{width:100.125%}
```

If you really need to reuse the variable, you might want to consider making a function for it.

Comment: @Will I've updated it, seems to be something not right going on with the variable assignment somewhere.

Comment: + 1 for the debug thing.  i'm off to find out what that does. : )

Comment: Yep the variable wasn't getting set.  Odd.  I got round it as per my answer below - works well, not 100% sure why.   Unsporting to accept mine over yours so - win to you - thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

So I have solved it by using decimals, and using the percentage function to switch to % (move the decimal place)  and set the units.

```
$one-span-width: 0.0821875;
$gap: 0.00125;
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
 $span-width:  ($one-span-width * $i) + ($gap * $i) ;    
 .span#{$i}{
  width: percentage($span-width);     
 }
}
```